# Nginx language redirect: /de/test/test.php to /test/test.php?

Tags: nginx, redirect, configuration

I'm trying to configure Nginx on a new server. I have a number of PHP scripts (f.e. /test/test.php) and I want to use this scripts "as is" (default language, English), as well as with language redirecting. Example - when "/de/test/test.php" is requested,

1. nginx writes a cookie (lang=de)
2. and returns "/test/test.php" (without modifying URI, so that visitor
   remains on "/de/test/test.php"

Any help is greatly appreciated! I already lost several nights fighting with this, and I'm getting desperate enough to cancel new server and return back to shared hosting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if it works:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    location ~* /(de|fr)/test/test\.php$ {
        set $lang $1;
        add_header  Cookie 'lang=$lang';
        rewrite (.*) /test/test.php last;
        break;
    }
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi.conf;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
    error_page 404 /error/404.php;
}
```